# list index out of range error in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get the user statuses from Weibo, but I keep having this error.

```
import re
import string
import sys
import os
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import etree

reload(sys) 
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
if(len(sys.argv)>=2):
    user_id = (int)(sys.argv[1])
else:
    user_id = (int)(raw_input("input user_id: "))

cookie = {"Cookie": "******my cookies"}
url = 'http://weibo.cn/u/%d?filter=1&page=1'%user_id

html = requests.get(url, cookies = cookie).content
selector = etree.HTML(html)
pageNum = (int)(selector.xpath('//input[@name="mp"]')[0].attrib['value'])

result = "" 
urllist_set = set()
word_count = 1
image_count = 1

print 'spider is ready...'

for page in range(1,pageNum+1):

  url = 'http://weibo.cn/u/%d?filter=1&page=%d'%(user_id,page) 
  lxml = requests.get(url, cookies = cookie).content


  selector = etree.HTML(lxml)
  content = selector.xpath('//span[@class="ctt"]')
  for each in content:
    text = each.xpath('string(.)')
    if word_count>=4:
      text = "%d :"%(word_count-3) +text+"\n\n"
    else :
      text = text+"\n\n"
    result = result + text
    word_count += 1


fo = open("/Users/apple/Desktop/%s"%user_id, "wb")
fo.write(result)
word_path=os.getcwd()+'/%d'%user_id
print 'done'
```

Error:

```
File "weibo_spider.py", line 25, in <module>
    pageNum = (int)(selector.xpath('//input[@name="mp"]')[0].attrib['value'])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: you are assuming that `selector.xpath('//input[@name="mp"]')` will match no matter what? This is issue. Think if there is no input with name "mp" then how can you find it's attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assuming `selector.path` will always find something, but this isn't true most of cases. So build habit of defensive programming. See [Defensive Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming)

Try replacing

```
pageNum = (int)(selector.xpath('//input[@name="mp"]')[0].attrib['value'])
```

With:

```
controls = selector.xpath('//input[@name="mp"]')
if controls:
     pageNum = int(controls[0].attrib['value'])
```

Comment: Hmm, I found this error
pageNum = (int)control[0].attrib['value'])
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Lucia, you are using `control`. are you spelling it correctly? in my example it's `controls`

Comment: same error,  File "weibo_spider.py", line 27
    pageNum = (int)controls[0].attrib['value'])
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Do you see extra `)` at end of troubling line? remove it. Or recopy code I posted above.

Comment: oh, sorry for the mistake. But it keeps popping up the same error even after I remove the bracket: File "weibo_spider.py", line 27
    pageNum = (int)controls[0].attrib['value'] 
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Well, you really need to learn python syntax and find out what's wrong. I don't see what are you trying is equals to what I posted above. see ` pageNum = int(controls[0].attrib['value'])`

Comment: Thank you! it works now. I'm new to Python. But there's one problem, it only returns 27 tweets, I suppose it will return all the tweets

Comment: Well, how do you know there are more than 27 tweets or even less  than 27? It could be paging or even throttling! So I'd suggest do some research and I'm positive you can find solution.